# LLenar 'DataSet1' con datos de textbox para mostrar en informe SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs

Tengo un `webform` en el cual tengo un formulario y necesito pasar lo que el usuario escriba en esos `textbox` a un reporte SSRS.(Primero intente esto agregando parámetros al informe pero no funciono, seguí el tutorial de este  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOlgt.png) solo que yo uso webform  c#)

Primero cree un DataSet.xsd con un `DataTable` y agregue las columnas correspondientes a los textbox, aquí paso el valor de los textbox a las columnas de la tabla del dataset

He editado mi codigo asi y ya no marca error,

```html
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
DataSet1.SolicitudDataTable dt = new DataSet1.SolicitudDataTable();
DataSet1.SolicitudRow row = dt.NewSolicitudRow();
row.codigo = codigo.Text;
row.nombre = nombre.Text;
row.status = status.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
 ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("../../Rdlc/SF.rdlc");
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

El problema ahora es que mi reporte SSRS aparece en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi fue como agregue los campos del DataSet al informe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Diganme que hice mal

Finalmente lo he resuelto asi, por si a alguien le sirve

```html
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
reportDataSource.Value = dt;                   
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("../../Rdlc/SF.rdlc");
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que este faltando la linea

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
```

en donde indicas que es un reporte local

Ademas si creas un `xsd` se supone que debes usarlos y no instanciar un datatable comun, el xsd define las columnas por lo tanto deberias instanciarlo desde este

```
CustomDataSet ds= new CustomDataSet(); 
CustomDataSet.CustomDataTable dt = CustomDataSet.CustomDataTable();
CustomDataSet.CustomDataTableRow row = dt.NewRowCustom();
row.codigo = codigo.Text;
//resto
dt.Rows.Add(row);

ds.CustomDataTable = dt;
```

la idea es que asignes en base al uso del dataset tipado que definio el xsd

Nota: lo del "custom" que uses es un nombre generico, debes cambiarlo por el que define el xsd

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, ya actualice la pregunta utilizando su codigo pero me marca error, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: el intellisense del VS te lista ese nombre para el datatable ? el NewRow() tambien deberia cambiar, por uno que lleva el nombre de la tabla

Comment: hola ya edite mi pregunta de nuevo en la ultima linea nose como solucionarlo, gracias